# Block chrome or firefox from accessing localhost

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, proxy, localhost, lamp

Is there a way to block chrome or firefox from accessing anything located at localhost?

I built my web application on top of a LAMP stack @ localhost and it's kind of big (for me) and I would like to test it, but when I access site.com it loads all the resources that are linked on http://localhost/ because they are on my machine but it doesnt load those resources when I try to access the website from another computer.

So, I need to test the application and it would be nice to just block localhost completely.

A workaround I found was using a proxy addon in firefox and blacklisting http://localhost/* but it's extremely slow because the proxies are free.

So I would like to find a way to just block localhost completely in any of these browsers and that would make my life much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading your post I got the impression that the website you are building uses absolute URLs to `http://localhost/some.html` If this is true, please fix your application to use relative URLs like `some.html` or `/site.html`.

If my impression was wrong and you still want to block localhost from your browser, you could misuse the "[proxy auto-config](https://calomel.org/proxy_auto_config.html)" feature in your browser. Save the following into a local file (say, ~/proxy.pac):

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
{
  if (isInNet(host, "127.0.0.1", "255.255.255.255"))
    {return "PROXY 127.0.0.1:65535";}
  if (dnsDomainIs(host, "localhost"))
    {return "PROXY 127.0.0.1:65535";}
  else
    {return "DIRECT";}
}
```

In Firefox, go to Preferences/Advanced/Network/Connection Settings... Choose "Automatic proxy configuration URL" and specify the full path for the saved file. The browser will try to use a SOCKS proxy at 127.0.0.1:65535 that does not exist and will fail reading any local files through http or https.

Comment: It looks like the latest Firefox ignores the proxy configuration for localhost.